# delayed_job vs. cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, delayed-job, whenever

I have a system where users come in to go through an application process that has multiple parts - sometimes users will save their progress and come back later.

I want to send users an e-mail if they haven't come back in 48 hours - would it be best to do this using `cron`, `delayed_job`, or `whenever`?

I've noticed that whenever I run operations in the console (such as `bundle install` or `rake db:migrate`) it runs cron as well, which makes me suspicious that we may have instances where users get multiple reminders in the same day.

What are your recommendations for this?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, Whenever and Cron are synonymous. All Whenever does is provide a way for you to write cronjobs using Ruby (which is awesome, I love Whenever).

Delayed_job is not the answer here. You definitely want to use cronjobs. Create a method on your Application model that will get applications which have an `updated_at` value of `< 2.days.ago` and e-mail its applicant.

```
def notify_stale_applicants
  @stale_applications = Application.where('updated_at < ?', 2.days.ago) # or 48.hours.ago
  @stale_applications.each do |app|
    UserMailer.notify_is_stale(app).deliver
  end
end
```

And your UserMailer:

```
def notify_is_stale(application)
  @application = application
  mail(:to => application.user.email, :from => "Application Status <status@yourdomain.com>", :subject => "You haven't finished your Application!"
end
```

Using whenever to create this cron:

```
every :day, :at => '8am' do
  runner 'Application.notify_stale_applicants'
end
```